# The 'this' keyword still refer to window after I bind it

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to animate letters in a string one after the other like how dominoes fall. The *this* keyword inside the handler function refers to *window*, how can I fix this?

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.mouseTarget = document.querySelector('#target');
    this.letters = document.querySelectorAll('.letter');
    
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);

    this.mouseTarget.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.handler, false);
    this.mouseTarget.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.handler, false);
  }

  handler(event) {
    if (event.type === 'mouseenter') {
      setTimeout(function() {
        this.letters.forEach(function(letter) {
          letter.classList.add('active');
        });
      }, 300);
    }
    else if (event.type === 'mouseleave') {
      setTimeout(function() {
        this.letters.forEach(function(letter) {
          letter.classList.add('inactive');
        });
      }, 300);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.mouseTarget.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => this.handler(), false);`

Comment: `function() {}` has its own scope in js.  If you want the functions inside the setTimeout to use the same scope as the parent object, use "fat arrow" functions instead

Comment: Tried to add an answer but couldn't before question was closed. You're adding a function inside `setTimeout`, which has its own `this` context. Change it to an arrow function, which has no `this` context. Replace the line with `setTimeout(() => {`